# Como alterar a visualização das options de um select em dispositivos móveis?

Tags: css, mobile, jquery-mobile

Antes de começar a limpar meus arquivos de CSS e de JS, quando abria um `select` no meu dispositivo móvel (Windows Phone com IE)  ele abria as opções numa tela preta que se sobrepunha à da página, e só desaparecia depois da `option` ser selecionada (ou da operação ser cancelada pelo botão voltar).

Algo mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas agora isso parou de funcionar, e está abrindo da forma normal (e indesejada), assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Durante este processo eu removi toda CSS que não era utilizada à partir de uma página rodando no navegador, deixei de referenciar a JQuery Mobile (mas já inclui de novo e tenho quase certeza de que não era isso)...

O `meta name "viewport"` está assim:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
```

Estou usando o [`selectpicker`](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), e o HTML está assim:

```
<label for="Cdiainicio">
                <select name="Tdiainicio" id="Cdiainicio" class="selectpicker" data-width="70px">
                    <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/models/scripts/datas/combos/combodia.html"?>
                </select>
            </label>
```

(Já tentei retirar o `data-width` mas não resolveu)

No arquivo `combodia.html` estão as options:

```
<option value='dia'>Dia</option>
<option value='01'>1</option>
<option value='02'>2</option>
<option value='03'>3</option>
<option value='04'>4</option>
<option value='05'>5</option>
<option value='06'>6</option>
<option value='07'>7</option>
<option value='08'>8</option>
<option value='09'>9</option>
<option value='10'>10</option>
<option value='11'>11</option>
<option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
<option value='15'>15</option>
<option value='16'>16</option>
<option value='17'>17</option>
<option value='18'>18</option>
<option value='19'>19</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
<option value='21'>21</option>
<option value='22'>22</option>
<option value='23'>23</option>
<option value='24'>24</option>
<option value='25'>25</option>
<option value='26'>26</option>
<option value='27'>27</option>
<option value='28'>28</option>
<option value='29'>29</option>
<option value='30'>30</option>
<option value='31'>31</option>
```

Então o que gostaria de saber é **como este comportamento é alterado**? Tem a ver com a jQuery Mobile? Pode ser alguma coisa nas CSS's?

Comment: Não entendi qual é a dúvida, se quer usar o seletor *default* é só remover a classe `selectpicker`, não?!

Comment: Não, nos navegadores eu quero que apareça com o selectpicker, e mesmo nos dispositivos mobile, quero que apareça com o select picker. Só nos dispositivos mobile, quando abrir as `options`, quero que abra daquela forma que postei na imagem (as imagens estão abrindo aí?) Valeu.

Comment: Ah, então, vc tem razão, sem o select picker abriu da forma desejada...  Na verdade acho então que não foi retirar CSS, mas incluir (o selectpicker)... Mas então, usando o selctpicker não tem jeito de obter este mesmo comportamento? @renan

Comment: Em todos os navegadores *mobile* você quer que tenha a aparência do Windows Phone? Ou só no Windows mesmo?

Comment: Em todos eu gostaria que tivesse o mesmo tipo de comportamento (se é que outros dispositivos tem esse mesmo tipo de comportamento), ou seja, que usasse o padrão do celular, abrindo esta tela que ocupa toda área de navegação, aparecendo as opções grandes e tal... @renan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript para obter o `userAgent` e checar se o usuário está acessando o site com um navegador *mobile*. Se o valor for verdadeiro, basta remover a classe que altera a aparência do `select`.

Você pode usar o regex do site [*detect mobile browsers*](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) para isso.

```js
var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(ua)) {

   /* Remove a classe 'selectpicker'. */
   document.getElementById('meu-select')
           .classList
           .remove('selectpicker');
}
```

Comment: Pra usar com classe uso `document.getElementsByClassName`?  Valeu, não testei ainda, mas acho que isso vai resolver não só este problema, como permite alterar tudo que eu achar útil para os dispositivos mobile né... Valeu!

Comment: Então, não consegui fazer funcionar mesmo por `id`... o inspetor  diz que a variável  `vendor` não está definida. Preciso alterar alguma coisa?

Comment: @gustavox qual navegador? Como está seu código?

Comment: Chrome, o código está idêntico ao que vc postou, só mudei a `id`...

Comment: Então, eu já entendi o ponto, então já dei como resolvido...qualquer coisa se não conseguir mesmo peço um help. Valeu!

Comment: @gustavox eu testei aqui e funcionou normalmente, o problema era no meu código?

Comment: Vou tentar criar um fiddle aqui...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/57gxf079/3/ Coloquei dois selects, já com o select picker, tentando pegar por classe (mas já coloquei os id's nos selects caso não dê pra fazer por classe)... valeu pela ajuda cara!

Comment: Então, ainda não consegui fazer funcionar mesmo... vc poderia por favor dar uma olhada no fiddle, pra ver onde estou errando? Valeu desde já.

Comment: @gustavox `getElementsByClassName` retorna vários elementos, então se você precisa percorrer todos é necessário fazer um *loop*. No `getElementsByClassName` não precisa usar ponto para indicar que é uma classe, por isso que `.selectpicker` não vai funcionar.

Comment: Se quiser pegar o primeiro elemento com classe `selectpicker`, pode fazer assim: `document.getElementsByClassName('selectpicker')[0].classList.remove('selectpicker'); ` - http://jsfiddle.net/57gxf079/4/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30235/discussion-between-renan-and-gustavox).